# How to get access token from API request and pass it to other response using Cypress

Tags: javascript, get, token, cypress

I'm beginner in Cypress and I don't understand how can I get  token  "access_token"
value from response and pass it to new request header?

My response body example

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9",
"refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9",
"storage_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
```

}
I need to get access_token value

Answer (score 0):

If you are already logged in, you could use `sessionStorage` to access a session object, like `token` in your case. So, before defining your next request, you could declare it as a variable and pass to the request body:

```
 const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
 cy.request({
       method: 'your_method',
       url: 'your_endpoint',
       auth: {
          bearer: token,
       },
 });
```